# Oracle Pivot with aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate, average

I have this table:

```
id  |  attr  |  val
1      'A'      1.2
1      'A'      2.4
1      'B'      2.4 
1      'B'      0.5
2      'A'      0.8
2      'A'      1.6
2      'B'      1.8
2      'B'      2.0
```

For each id, I'd like to average the values `avg(val)` across each common attribute.
I tried the following:

```
select id, 
    case when count(case when attr = 'A' then 1 end) > 0 
        then round(avg(val),2) end A,
    case when count(case when attr = 'B' then 1 end) > 0 
        then round(avg(val),2) end B,
    case when count(case when attr = 'C' then 1 end) > 0 
        then round(avg(val),2) end C
from table where this = 'that'
group by id;
```

The pivot/avg works for the first attr but then the other attributes get the same value:

```
id  |  A  |  B
1     1.8   1.8 
2     1.2   1.2
```

I then tried this, but each attribute was output on a new row:

```
  select id, 
      case when attr = 'A' then round(avg(val),2) end A,
      case when attr = 'B' then round(avg(val),2) end B,
      case when attr = 'C' then round(avg(val),2) end C,
  from table where this = 'that'
  group by id, attr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` as

```
  with tab( id, attr, val) as
  (
     select 1,'A',1.2 from dual union all
     select 1,'A',2.4 from dual union all
     select 1,'B',2.4 from dual union all 
     select 1,'B',0.5 from dual union all
     select 2,'A',0.8 from dual union all
     select 2,'A',1.6 from dual union all
     select 2,'B',1.8 from dual union all
     select 2,'B',2.0 from dual   
  )    
  select id, 
         round(avg(case when attr = 'A' then val end),2) A,
         round(avg(case when attr = 'B' then val end),2) B
    from tab 
   group by id

   ID   A     B
   ---  ----  ----
   1    1,80  1,45
   2    1,20  1,90
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/FPVI6103)</kbd>